# Error compiling LaTeX file after modifying entry in bibliography file

Tags: bibliographies, bibtex, compiling

I have a .tex file that was running normally, but when I changed the reference year of a citation in the .bib file, an error keeps appearing. I have tried clearing the cache using the command "del *.aux *.bbl *.blg *.log *.out *.toc", but I can't seem to resolve the issue.

The error message displayed is as follows:

```
This is BibTeX, Version 0.99d (MiKTeX 23.1)
The top-level auxiliary file: principal.aux
I couldn't open style file abbrvnatLSMR.bst
---line 29 of file principal.aux
: \bibstyle{abbrvnatLSMR
: }
I'm skipping whatever remains of this command
I found no style file---while reading file principal.aux
(There were 2 error messages)
The process exited with error(s).
```

Comment: Did you actually read the error message? You are missing a file (the style file), why should cleaning up auxiliary files help here.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. The error messsage is actually reasonably self-explanatory: "I couldn't open style file abbrvnatLSMR.bst". This message could have several causes. E.g., there might be a typo in the `\bibliographystyle` directive. Or, the file `abbrvnatLSMR.bst` currently does not exist on your system and still needs to be downloaded and activated. Or, the file does exist on your system but isn't located in a directory that's searched by BibTeX. Unless you tell us (a lot!) more about your LaTeX and BibTeX setup, it won't be possible to provide a more thorough diagnosis of the situation.

Comment: Urike, sure, I have read the error message. As I mentioned in my previous question, everything was running normally. I only changed the year of reference and saved the file. Since I have a backup of the file that was functioning properly, I tried again to see if I had made any mistakes, but I only changed the year of reference. I have cleared the cache because I have read that it could work when you change something in bib file, however, it was not the case. When everything was working, I didn't have this file abbrvnatLSMR.bst.

Comment: @Mico, thank you for your answer. When I read that it could be a typo in the \bibliographystyle, I decided to change the style and it actually worked. I don't know why, but with the previous style, when I made changes to my .bib file, LaTeX couldn't "update" the file. After changing it, I was able to modify my .bib file and it worked! Thank you.